# Change Column Headers in Array with Unset: PHP

Tags: php, unset

I'm trying to change the text that gets written to the first row, column header, of my csv. I'm trying to use `unset`, but it's not working. Am I referencing the wrong array? Any help would be appreciated. My code is below:

```
for ($x=0; $x<$count; $x++)
{
    $currentRecord = $response['data'][$x];
    $jsonDataInArray[] = array
    (
        "b98336b40c8420dc2f1401d6451b1b47198eee6d" => $response['data'][$x]['b98336b40c8420dc2f1401d6451b1b47198eee6d'],
        "17a14a9da9815451ff5ffc669d407e8b0376b06b" => $response['data'][$x]['17a14a9da9815451ff5ffc669d407e8b0376b06b'],
        "3eedd4fd08f44a72d911dc4934a6916f3b31911b" => $response['data'][$x]['3eedd4fd08f44a72d911dc4934a6916f3b31911b'],
        "52ede287f6c55eb6b12821ca24f74098779abdce" => $response['data'][$x]['52ede287f6c55eb6b12821ca24f74098779abdce'],
        "13916ba291ab595f27aefbff8b6c43a3fb467b72" => $response['data'][$x]['13916ba291ab595f27aefbff8b6c43a3fb467b72']
    )
)

//change key names.
$jsonDataInArray["Col1"] = $jsonDataInArray["b98336b40c8420dc2f1401d6451b1b47198eee6d"];
unset($jsonDataInArray["b98336b40c8420dc2f1401d6451b1b47198eee6d"]);

//first row of data 
$test_array = $jsonDataInArray[0];



//open file to write towards
if($startPos == 0){
    $fp = fopen('output.csv', 'w');
    fputcsv($fp, array_keys($response['data'][0]));
}else{
    $fp = fopen('output.csv', 'a');
}

//write data
foreach ($jsonDataInArray as $fields)
{
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
```

My current output is:

```
b98336b40c8420dc2f1401d6451b1b47198eee6d|17a14a9da9815451ff5ffc669d407e8b0376b06b|3eedd4fd08f44a72d911dc4934a6916f3b31911b|52ede287f6c55eb6b12821ca24f74098779abdce
4616|||stuff
```

My desired output would be

```
Col1|17a14a9da9815451ff5ffc669d407e8b0376b06b|3eedd4fd08f44a72d911dc4934a6916f3b31911b|52ede287f6c55eb6b12821ca24f74098779abdce
4616|||stuff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$jsonDataInArray` has numerical indexes, each of which contains an array.

Replace

```
$jsonDataInArray["Col1"] = $jsonDataInArray["b98336b40c8420dc2f1401d6451b1b47198eee6d"];
unset($jsonDataInArray["b98336b40c8420dc2f1401d6451b1b47198eee6d"]);
```

with

```
$jsonDataInArray[0]["Col1"] = $jsonDataInArray[0]["b98336b40c8420dc2f1401d6451b1b47198eee6d"];
unset($jsonDataInArray[0]["b98336b40c8420dc2f1401d6451b1b47198eee6d"]);
```

to have it work in your test, but you'll probably want to replace that with a loop to have it change for each entry.

Answer (score 1):

You are outputting from the wrong array

Change this section to use `$jsonDataInArray` and not `$response`

```
//open file to write towards
if($startPos == 0){
    $fp = fopen('output.csv', 'w');
    fputcsv($fp, array_keys($jsonDataInArray));
}else{
    $fp = fopen('output.csv', 'a');
}
```

Comment: Vote up for your response. This would work, but it's giving me `1,2,3,4,etc...` as my column headers, because those are the keys in that array.

Comment: I wish I could accept both your answers as the end all answer because you both helped me get to the proper code. I voted you up and gave dAngelov the green check because he has less points and could use some